# How many ways are there to write the multiplication table of a Group with 2 elements?

Tags: group-theory

My teacher gave us an exercise problem which states

> Write down all the possible multiplication tables for a group $G$ with only two elements $e$ and $g$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$.

But isn’t there only one table?

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\, & e & g\\
\hline
e & e & g\\
g & g & e
\end{array}.$$

Comment: Perhaps your instructor wants you to prove that?  All you need to show, of course, is that $g^2=e$,  which is not difficult.

Comment: There is also the table $\begin{array}{c|cc}
\, & g & e\\
\hline
g & e & g\\
e & g & e
\end{array}$ which, depending on how you define "different", is different. You could also swap the rows but not the columns, and similarly the columns but not the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you are absolutely correct with your group table (correctly filled out).
My guess is that you only had to decide on the element $g\ \star\ g$ as to whether that would be $g$ or $e$.  If $g\ \star\ g$ were $g$, then it would follow that $g\ =\ e$. That is, the group has two identity elements that are different. But being that $G$ is a group, there can only be one and only one identity element. Hence, this leaves you with the one and only. one choice for the element $g\ \star\ g$ and that is  $g\ \star\ g\ =\ e$, which brings us to your group table. All other group tables written with two elements are isomorphic to your group table (in the sense, that no matter how the two elements are labeled the corresponding group table matches up with yours).